# Residual sum of squares and variance.

Tags: statistics, regression, variance, anova

So, from the ANOVA table one can get an output of residual sum of squares. Should the RSS be divided by degrees of freedom in ANOVA + 1 or should it be divided by df in ANOVA - 1? Because the residual variance formula is: $\frac{\left((\hat{y}_i - y_i) - \overline{(\hat{y}_i - y_i)}\right)^2 }{n-2}$. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RSS in ANOVA should be divided by the number observations $n$ minus the number of groups $K$, i.e.,
$$
MSE = \frac{RSS}{n-K},
$$
the reason is that RSS is the weighted sum of the variances of each group.  For every group you estimate its mean $\mu_j$ with $\bar{x}_{n_j\cdot}$, hence you "lose" one degree of freedom every estimator, i.e.,  $RSS = \sum_{j=1}^K (n_j-1) S^2_j$, where $S_j^2 = \frac{1}{n_j -1}\sum_{i=1}^{n_j}(x_{ij} - \bar{x}_{n_j\cdot})^2$